# Sendgrid integration: How to host AASA file on same domain as CNAME redirect

Tags: branch.io

How can I host the AASA file on the same domain where the CNAME redirects to thirdparty.bnc.lt ? Trying to download the AASA will just always redirect to thirdparty.bnc.lt, won't it?

Here's where I'm stuck:
1. Begin setup of Sendgrid email integration
2. Step 2 (Configure ESP): put in the correct info (see pic) 
[image]

3. Get these errors (although notice the CNAME is happy):
   [image]
4. How can the AASA ever be found/valid when the click tracking domain redirects to thirdparty.bnc.lt

Answer (score -1):

It could be because the AASA file hosted on your domain is incorrectly formatted. Here is a sample AASA file contents for your reference:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "3XXXXX9M83.io.branch-labs.Branchster",
        "paths": [ "NOT /e/*", "*", "/", “/archives/201?/* ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Please check out our [blog](https://blog.branch.io/what-is-an-aasa-apple-app-site-association-file/) to know more about AASA files.

If you have already tried this and still facing issue let us know or write to us at integrations@branch.io and we'll be happy to provide you with the required support!

Comment: We will also help generate SSL certificates. Please write to ntegrations@branch.io   for that.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the OP's basic question: *How can the AASA ever be found/valid when the click tracking domain redirects to thirdparty.bnc.lt*?